# How to get FragmentManager in a class extends LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a class TitleView extends LinearLayout with a button in it. Since there are servral UIs need this class , I included it in those layout xml files. Now I need to start a PreferenceFragment after the button is pressed， but I just can't use getFragmentManager() to obtain FragmentManager to control the PreferenceFragment in TitleView.

Can anyone help me out ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why don't you define a constructor that accepts `Context` and `FragmentManager`?

Comment: cuz this class is included in xml files and system calls the default constructor.

Comment: I already solve the problem by using a setActivity obtain current activity. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TitleView extends LinearLayout
{

    private FragmentActivity mActivity;

    /**
     * @param of type null
     * @return mActivity of type FragmentActivity
     * getter function for mActivity
     * @since May 3, 2013 
     * @author rajeshcp 
     */
    public FragmentActivity getmActivity() {
        return mActivity;
    }

    /**
     * @param mActivity of type FragmentActivity
     * @return of type null
     * setter function for mActivity
     * @since May 3, 2013
     * @author rajeshcp 
     */
    public void setmActivity(FragmentActivity mActivity) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    public TitleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

}

((TitleView)findViewbyId(R.id.your_lay_out_id)).setmActivity(yourFragmentActivity);

mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: thanks a lot pal, but i need to get FragmentManager inside class TitleView in order to bind listener to the button.

Comment: why you want fragment manager to add listener to the button ?

Comment: sorry for my poor english. I need something like this: public void onClick(View v){mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragement()).commit();}

Comment: I already solve the problem by using a setActivity obtain current activity. Thanks for the hint!